# How can I render inner html in an Angular MatAutoComplete MatOption user selection?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of properties, some of which include HTML tags for superscript or subscript. I am able to show these values correctly in an Angular Material MatAutoComplete list. I cannot find a way to show a user's MatOption selection correctly. In other words, the user selection shows the raw HTML for these tags. Here is the relevant HTML for my component. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<mat-form-field>
<input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="property" [matAutocomplete]= "propertyAutoComplete">
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #propertyAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith">
<mat-option *ngFor="let property of filteredPropertyOptions | async" [value]="property" (onSelectionChange)="selectedProperty(property)">
<div innerHTML="{{property.name}}"></div>
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-autocomplete  autoActiveFirstOption   #propertyAutoComplete="matAutocomplete"  [displayWith]="displayWith"> <mat-option *ngFor="let property of filteredPropertyOptions" [value]="property"{{property.name }}/mat-option></mat-autocomplete>`

Comment: can you please put comments on your answer